# Times a song has been played on Spotify using spotipy

Tags: python, spotipy

Is there a way to get the field number that a song has been played on a playlist on a specific country using spotipy?

Answer (score 0):

No.
From what I've read from spotify API's documentation you can not get that info from it.
Here is the link of the documentation of track features:

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/tracks/get-audio-features/

*analysis_url* - may have some extra features not describe at this page.